# Adding file to project which is outside of the project directory

Tags: phpstorm

I have a following root structure

```
dir1
dir2
index_dir
dir3
...
index.php
```

I wanna have a project in phpStorm (7.1.3) so that I see only index_dir and index.php

the problem is that if I create a new project via "Open directory" I will have only index_dir in my project. I would like to add the file index.php to that project and not every other directory. How can I do that. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: You can create project in the "root" and just **exclude unwanted folders**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always setup an include path to a lower level directory but this will not work if you project is in the directory of you external library / included path (endless loop)

[image: PhpStorm Add include path]

The way you suggest it can just not be done

EDIT :

Although you cannot hide those other directories, you can ignore them

[image: PhpStorm Ignore directories]

Ignored directories will not be indexed

EDIT 2017 :
In the later versions of PHPStorm, eg v2017.1 and later you can now open multiple projects int he same window, this is by far the best solution you will ever get.

Answer (score 7):

Recent versions of PHPStorm (circa 2018+) support multiple "content roots" which allow you to point to project files in different hierarchies.

In the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), click Directories. The Directories page opens.

To add a content root, click click Add Content Root in the right-hand pane and then select the required folder in the dialog that opens.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-project-structure.html#adding_content_root

Comment: A quick alternative flow to do the same thing is to click on `File > Open...`, then select a directory, and choose `Attach` when asked what to do with the resource. But it does the same exact thing, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom scope to your overall PS project.

For instance, I am working on an app called Quicklinks, and I only need a subset of the files in my overall WordPress install. I only want to see files with the word `quicklinks` in the file or directory name. To do this, I set up the following scope pattern in **Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes**:

`file:*quicklinks*/`

This looks for any file or directory anywhere in my overall project containing the string `quicklinks` in its name.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Utse.png)

In the OP's case, a scope with this pattern should work:

`file:index*/`

Beware that empty directories may not be included.